# Identifier cout is undefined

Tags: command-line, compiling, gcc, c++

I am compiling below code with GCC-12 compiler on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have 2 different versions of GCC installed on my machine 11 and 12.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
}
```

This is my tasks.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "Build with GCC 11",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-11",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6",
                "-lstdc++",
                "-std=c++17",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

and I am getting the following error

> Executing task: Build with GCC 12
>
> Starting build... /usr/bin/gcc-12 -fdiagnostics-color=always -g
> -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -lstdc++ -std=c++20 /home/pratham/Downloads/C++/hello.cpp -o
> /home/pratham/Downloads/C++/hello
>
> gcc-12: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or
> directory compilation terminated.
>
> Build finished with error(s).
>
> - The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).
> - Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Comment: did you installed `build-essential`?

Comment: Yes, it is installed to the newest version

Comment: You should be using `g++` not `gcc` to compile C++ code - the error `cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory` is consistent with g++-12 not being installed on your system, only gcc-12

Comment: thanks man, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your question title and the one in the body are different.

```
undefined reference to `std::cout'
```

occurs when both gcc and g++ are installed, but you try to compile C++ code by invoking the C compiler `gcc`, instead of the C++ compiler `g++`. Although `gcc` can recognize and compile C++ code (by calling the corresponding `cc1plus` frontend), it does not automatically link the C++ standard library `libstdc++` as it would when you use `g++` - and so fails at the link phase<sup>1</sup>.

On the other hand,

```
gcc-12: fatal error: cannot execute ‘cc1plus’: execvp: No such file or directory
```

occurs when you try to compile C++ with `gcc`, but the corresponding `g++` (which provides `cc1plus`) is not even installed - presumably that is the case when you set `"command": "/usr/bin/gcc-12".

Either way, you should use `g++` (or `g++-11` or `g++-12` etc. if you want to specify a particular version) rather than `gcc` / `gcc-11` / `gcc-12` when compiling C++ code.

---

1. if you're curious about these things, you can verify that by executing `gcc hello.cpp -lstdc++`

Comment: Now I understood the difference between this 2 errors, thank you @steeldriver.